# Write contents of URL request to file

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to fetch a list from a php file using python and save it to a file:

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://crypto-bot.hopto.org/server/list.php')

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(str(page))
f.close()

print(page.read())
```

Output on screen (divided onto four lines for readability):

```
ALF\nAMC\nANC\nARG\nBQC\nBTB\nBTE\nBTG\nBUK\nCAP\nCGB\nCLR\nCMC\nCRC\nCSC\nDGC\n
DMD\nELC\nEMD\nFRC\nFRK\nFST\nFTC\nGDC\nGLC\nGLD\nGLX\nHBN\nIXC\nKGC\nLBW\nLKY\n
LTC\nMEC\nMNC\nNBL\nNEC\nNMC\nNRB\nNVC\nPHS\nPPC\nPXC\nPYC\nQRK\nSBC\nSPT\nSRC\n
STR\nTRC\nWDC\nXPM\nYAC\nYBC\nZET\n
```

Output in file:

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00000000031DAEF0>
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) ([`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) in Python 3).

In the console:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlretrieve('http://crypto-bot.hopto.org/server/list.php','test.txt') 
('test.txt', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x101338050>)
```

This results in a file, `test.txt`, being saving in the current working directory with the contents

```
ALF
AMC
ANC
ARG
...etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read from the file object before writing to the file.  Also you should the same object to both file and screen.

Do this:

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://crypto-bot.hopto.org/server/list.php')

f = open("test.txt", "w")
content = page.read()
f.write(content)
f.close()

print(content)
```

Comment: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: I'm using `Python 3.5.1`

Comment: cast the byte stream to string like this content = str(page.read())

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading the content from the `urlopen` file-like when you write to the file.

Also, [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).