# save website as txt file

Tags: python-3.x, web, urllib, save-as

I would like to save a website as a txt file.  I managed to get this working with various websites using the code below (thanks to S.O. contributors):

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285966/write-contents-of-url-request-to-file"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

f = open("output.txt", "wb")
content = response.read()
f.write(content)
f.close()

print(content)
```

However, although this works for a Google Search URL, the resulting txt file does not seem to contain the required information from the page.  Here is an example of a URL link I am trying to save:
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=fin&ei=mOVMWszfDqzIgAaH54OoAg&q=JSE%3Agfi&oq=JSE%3Agfi&gs_l=finance-immersive.3..81i8k1.355270.355832.0.355925.3.3.0.0.0.0.241.241.2-1.1.0....0...1c..64.finance-immersive..2.1.240....0.7I3B1yH_BUk#scso=uid__eZMWrSaGqfUgAb6upTYDg_5:0,uid_GchNWpacMcKcgAbCyK7YBg_5:0&wptab=COMPANY

Although there is "Revenue" in the page, there is no "Revenue" in the txt file.  Is it perhaps a deliberate barrier designed by Google that "google.com/search" URLs do not save like other normal links?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this using Python, but if you want an Excel/VBA solution, you can run the code below and it will do what you want.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim retStr As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Navigate "http://www.wikihow.com/Choose-an-Email-Address"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    retStr = ie.document.body.innerText

    '~> Write the above to a text file
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant path
    FlName = "C:\your_path_here\Sample.Txt"

    filesize = FreeFile()

    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    Print #filesize, retStr
    Close #filesize
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```