# Zipfile: How to download a zipfile and save without extract?

Tags: python

I would like to download a zipfile from url and save somewhere. I don't want to extract my file and that is my problem. I have a code which download zipfile and extract files, but I want to only download and save. What should I change?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile


  zipurl = 'https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/prg/adresy/PunktyAdresowe/POLSKA.zip'
    with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
        with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
            zfile.extractall(r'/home/gis/adresypolska')  




Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 471, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 612, in _safe_read
    data = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

Comment: I think this is covered in the responses to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285966/write-contents-of-url-request-to-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `ZipFile` at all. You have the file content, write it out:

```py
zipurl = 'https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/prg/adresy/PunktyAdresowe/POLSKA.zip'
with open('POLSKA.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(urlopen(zipurl).read())
```

To read and save in chunks, in case you have small RAM:

```py
with open('POLSKA.zip', 'wb') as f:
    with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
        while True:
            chunk = zipresp.read(1024)
            if not chunk: break
            f.write(chunk)
```

This reads 1024 bytes every iteration, you should change it accordingly to your need.

Comment: I'am getting error: OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

Comment: @datasciencebegginer Can you give me the full traceback? It's working on my end.

Comment: I have already edited my post and I have added the error.

Comment: @datasciencebegginer Just a wild guess, but you probably have a faulty installation of Python. This seems like an OpenSSL improper compilation error.

Comment: I think the file which I try to download is too big. It has 9 GB.

Comment: @datasciencebegginer Hmm, then maybe you would want to read it in chunks. The example file only has 200Mb. Editing my answer for this scenario.

Comment: @cliff.wells oh wow, did not know it’s an outdated OpenSSL thing. Thanks for the info!